# Can you restrict the type of Type in a generic?

Tags: c#, generics, type-conversion

I have a dictionary where both the key and values are of type `Type`, like so...

```
private static Dictionary<Type, Type> myDict;
```

What I'm trying to do is restrict the second `Type` to only be types which inherit from `FrameworkElement`.

Note I'm not storing `FrameworkElement` instances, I'm trying to only store objects of type `Type` which derive from `FrameworkElement` making the following statement true...

```
var isTypeStorable = typeof(FrameworkElement).IsAssignableFrom(FooType);
```

So can that be done?

*BTW, yes, I know I can use the above to do runtime checking before adding to the dictionary (which is what I'm doing now).  I'm wondering if there's any features in the language which would let me restrict this at compile time.*

Comment: AFAIK no there is not. You could create a specialized dictionary, override the `Add` and `AddRange` methods, and throw if you get bad input, but this would still only provide run-time error checking. I almost wonder if there's a better way to do accomplish your ultimate goal, perhaps using a factory or some sort of DI? Can you elaborate a little on how the dictionary is used?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm currently doing.  This was more just wondering about the concept/capability in general as a feature of the language.

Comment: A Generic constraint doesn't help ? something like where `T : FrameworkElement`

Comment: @MrinalKamboj There's no `T`. We're working with instances of `Type` here.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj, in other words it's `T : Type` but I'm trying to further restrict it to a specific kind of type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**, that's not possible. `FrameworkElement.GetType()` and `FooType` have no relationship in the type system, both are just `Type`s. If you want to restrict your generic, you will have to do so with runtime checks and exceptions, the generic constraints will not help you here.

If you know what you want to store at compile time (or are happy with some complicated reflection) you could change your API to not take `Type`, but use the generic instead:

```
public void AddTypeForType(Type x, Type y)
```

could be replaced by

```
public void AddTypeForType<T1, T2>() where T1 : FrameworkElement
{
    myDict.Add(typeof(T1), typeof(T2));
}
```

You could then call it like this:

```
AddTypeForType<FrameworkDerivedClass, MyCustomClass>();
```

But that's more of an API change than an answer to your question.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by your second example.  You've specified two generic types which you aren't using in the signature.  Not even sure that would compile.  Plus, T1 is being restricted to a FrameworkElement *instance* not a Type. I'm trying to restrict it to a Type object that either is, or derives from the FrameworkElement type.

Comment: @MarqueIV Added an example of calling it. As I said, it's a change in API that comes close to what you want, but at the expense of being super-complicated to call if you don't know the actual types at compile time.

Comment: Interesting approach!  But now how would you call that at runtime with variables of type Type? ...or would you just use the regular Add method with manual checking at that point?

Comment: @MarqueIV If you know your Types at runtime only, you will be in for about 10 lines of reflection to call that method. *Really* ugly. Or you will need the normal runtime type checking with if/exception in a normal method as yo probably already have. That's why my answer says "no" :)

Comment: Well I'm marking yours as the answer for the creative use of the generics like that even though what I was hoping isn't possible.  It's a shame... it is possible in other languages. Ah well! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think there is nothing like that, But you can achieve this by checking the items before adding to the dictionary, I meant something like this:

Let `Xx,Yy` be an item that I wanted to add to the `myDict` SO what I can do is, First check for the existence of key and then for the condition for value(`inherit from FrameworkElement.`)

```
if(!myDict.ContainsKey(Xx) && /* Yy is inherited from FrameworkElement */)
{
   myDict.Add(Xx,Yy);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was doing with my 'isTypeStorable' flag.  Just wondering if I can get this at compile time, not runtime.

Comment: @MarqueIV what if I had `myDict.Add(CallExternalFunction(), CallExternalFunction())` how could the compiler know the returned type of `CallExternalFunction()` without running the function at compile time? It can't be done at compile time unless you switch to generics and use nvoigt's example.

Comment: That's not quite correct. The `Add` method is typed meaning if those functions didn't have the correct return type, the compiler would catch it.